# Covariance of vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matrices, vectors, normal-distribution, matlab, covariance

I am trying to solve a problem using MATLAB regarding Gaussian random vectors.
$$ S = ( S_{1} , S_{2} , S_{3} , S_{4}) \sim  N_{4}( \mu , Cov (S) ) $$
Given a 4*4 matrix Cov(S) and mu as a 4*1 matrix I have used the following code to calculate S and  $$\ find \ cov (X,Y) \ where\ X =\ (S_{1}) \ and \ Y =(S_{2},S_{3},S_{4})^T $$

S = mvnrnd(mu,SIGMA);

X = S(1,1);

Y = S(1,2:4);

EX = mu(1,1);

EY = mu(2:4,1);

covXY = (EX-X)*((EY-Y)');

The problem I have run into is that my result for Cov(X,Y) does not have positive values on the diagonal and is not symmetric, does this have anything to do with the fact that I am taking the covariance of two different sized vectors?

Comment: $S$ is a random variable. What do you mean by  "I have used the following code to calculate S" ?  Perhaps you intend to calculate the joint pdf of $S$? And if $S$ is multivariate Normal with known variance-covariance matrix, then what do you think $cov(X,Y)$ will provide that you do not already immediately have?

Comment: I am trying to compute the matrix Cov(X,Y),I believe this requires me to generate values for S via the MATLAB code however I may be wrong.

Comment: What is $Cov(W)$ then?

Comment: My mistake, that should be Cov(S), it is meant to represent $$ Cov(S_{i},S_{j})$$ Can I pull Cov(X,Y) directly from this matrix?